# pelican blog default category

Tags: categories, pelican

A static blog, created by Pelican, usually starts up by showing the blog. Blog entries can have different categories. Currently all blog entries are shown, sorted based on their date, regardless of their category.

Now, is it possible to change the settings, so that only blog entries of a ***specific category*** are shown on startup?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to do that you would need to create a theme and filter directly there !